# Flashloan Equalizer

Tags: solidity, polygon, flash-loans

I try to understand how to get a flashloan from euqlizer finance and make something with it. There is a documentation where they say I have to call the `onFlashLoan(...)` function to borrow the flashloan ([Equalizer Docs](https://docs.equalizer.finance/getting-started/how-do-i-borrow-a-flash-loan-a-deep-dive)).

But then I found a github repository where it is a full code example ([Equalizer Github](https://github.com/Equalizer-Finance/equalizer-smart-contracts-v1/blob/main/contracts/mock/FlashBorrowerMock.sol)), here I think the `flashBorrow(...)` funtion is borrowing the flashloan.

So my question is: Which function do I have to call to borrow a flashloan (`flashBorrow` or `onFlashLoan`), or do I have to call both?
If I only have to call one function, where is the connection between the two functions because there is no function calling the other one?

PS: If needed I can post the functions here, but it makes the question very long.

Thank you!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The `FlashBorrowerMock` example you've linked is the correct implementation.

It works like this:

1. You call `FlashBorrowerMock.flashBorrow(...)`.
2. `FlashBorrowerMock` calls `lender.flashLoan(...)` at the end.
3. `lender` calls `FlashBorrowerMock.onFlashLoan(...)` (it's a callback, see [link](https://github.com/Equalizer-Finance/equalizer-smart-contracts-v1/blob/main/contracts/FlashLoanProvider.sol#L89)).
4. Now you put your logic inside the `onFlashLoan` function.

Hope it's more clear!

Comment: Amazing, I was hoping for a answer like this. Thank you. 
But now I do have one more question. In `FlashBorrowerMock.flashBorrow(...)` the `fee` data is not used. Does the function have to make the repayment or where does it happen?

Comment: The repayment is automatically pulled. That's why in flashBorrow there's `token.approve`

Comment: Ok perfect thank you. Do you have a good page where I can read what a callback function is? I searched for it a long time and do not understand. Is it like a fallback function (Which is called if contract is called and no other function matches)?

Comment: @DaniS Callback function is just a fancy word for re-entering the previous contract. So if A calls B, and B calls A in the same function, then B is doing a callback.

Comment: Well, I got it now. Thank you very much!